# Inequality for the $r=|x-y|$ with $x,y$ in a ball

Tags: inequality

Notation: $ B_{2}$ is the open ball centered at zero with radius $2$

Let $x,y \in B_{2}$ and set $r = |x-y|$ , prove that for some $n \geq 0$ we have $4^{-n + 1} > r \geq 4^{-n}$

I have no idea how to do. A tip would be of great help.

Comment: Let $$n=\text{the least natural number such that }(4^{-n}\le r)$$ then you only need to prove that $4^{-k}\to 0$ as $k\to \infty$ and that $4^{-0}=1>r$.

Comment: I'm so sorry for my mistake

Comment: Substitute the last statement with $4^{-0+1}=4>r$. And, perhaps, you might also need the fact that $4^{-k}$ is strictly decreasing.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Who is k ?

Comment: A dummy integer variable.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see what this has to do with a "ball" or x and y.  The sequence $4^n$ converges to 0.  Given any number positive r, there exist n such that $4^n< r$.  The set of all such n has a least member so, for that n, $4^{-n}\le r< 4^{-n+1}$.

Comment: Well, if the ball had radius $100$, then you might have $r=35$, in which case $n\ge0$ would fail.

Comment: I'm so sorry for my mistake